# What is a channel name in postgreSQL? And where can I find it to monitor changes in a table?

Tags: python, postgresql

I would need to receive automatic notifications about changes in a specific table in postgreSQL using python.
I don't know what is a channel name, and where can I find it on pgAdmin.

Assuming I need to listen a table called 'table_1' and receive notifications about changes.
What I have to do?

Here's the code I've found online..

```
import select
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions

DB_NAME = "postgres"
DB_USER = "postgres"
DB_PASS = "pw"
DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_PORT = "5432"

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST, port=DB_PORT)
conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("LISTEN test;")

print "Waiting for notifications on channel 'test'"
while True:
    if select.select([conn],[],[],5) == ([],[],[]):
        print "Timeout"
    else:
        conn.poll()
        while conn.notifies:
            notify = conn.notifies.pop(0)
            print "Got NOTIFY:", notify.pid, notify.channel, notify.payload
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A channel is part of how LISTEN/NOTIFY works, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) for that feature.

You would need to create triggers on table_1 which issue notices whenever it is changed.  You could name the channel those notices are sent to 'table_1', if you want.  Or you could use one common channel for all tables you are listening to.  It is up to you.

You might instead want to use logical replication.  If is different way of doing a similar thing.